# Weighted features in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, random-forest

I am a beginner in machine learning. So any help or suggestion would be of great help.

I have read that putting weights on features and Predicting is a very bad idea. But what if few features needs to be weighted.

In a classification problem let's say it's a common norm that age is most dependent, how do I give weights to this feature. I was thinking to normalize it but with a variance of 1.5 or 2 (other features with variance 1), I believe that this feature will have more weight. Is this fundamentally wrong ? If wrong any other method.

Does it effect differently for classification and regression problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally if a feature has more Importance compared to other features and the model is Dense enough, with enough training sample, your model will automatically give it more Importance by optimizing weight matrices to account for that because we have partial derivatives in back propagation which calculate change by each connection, so it learns to give more importance to that feature on itself. If you don't normalize it, but scale it to a higher scale, you might have overstated it's important.

In practice a neural network works best if the inputs are centered and white. That means that their covariance is diagonal and the mean is the zero vector. This improves optimization of the neural net, since the hidden activation functions don't saturate that fast and thus do not give you near zero gradients early on in learning.

If you do scale just one feature up by a small value, it may or may not have desired effects, but the higher probability is of saturated gradients, so we avoid it.

Comment: Yes I do understand that. But how does it effect with normalizing with a higher variance for that feature ?

Comment: @game.changer Check the answer now, hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking specifically about random forests (as you tagged) then you can use the Weighted Subspace Random Forest algorithm (in R `wsrf` package). The algorithm determines a weight for each variable and then uses these during the model building.

> The informativeness of a variable with respect to the class is
>   measured by an information gain ratio. The measure is used as the
>   probability of that variable being selected for inclusion in the
>   variable subspace when splitting a specific node during the tree
>   building process. Therefore, variables with higher values by the
>   measure are more likely to be chosen as candidates during variable
>   selection and a stronger tree can be built.